# How to extend HTMLDomTree by C++

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer, dom

Hi C++ & JavaScript geeks,

I would like to create an IE plug-in which has the following features,

1. there is a button embedded the IE toolbar **(done)**
2. by clicking the button, it executes some pre-compiled c++ code which manipulates DOM tree **(done)**
3. I need to enhance step 2 to attach a native function to the 'window' object (e.g. `window.myfunc = function(a, b){return a + b;};`), and then 'eval' some pre-defined JavaScript which calls myfunc eventually.

I just have no idea how to 'extend' the existing object 'window'. Anyone can give me some clue?

Actually, I would like my plug-in works for both IE and Firefox/Chrome. But IE is the currently priority one.

**PS: It would also be cool if there is a way to register the function 'myfunc' to the global namespace of JavaScript execution context.**

Thanks,
Miles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. No one replies :(

Finally, I achieved the goal by creating a COM object which can be used in JavaScript. The weakness is the solution only works for IE.